# are the map and marker initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script         src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=aizaSyC04cjSCu3HVoez_JV2S4ePQGNNFwfj_9U&sensor=true">    </script>
```

```
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(41.669578,-0.907495);  
var marker;
var map;
var mapProp;

    function initialize()
    {
        mapProp = {
                      center:myCenter,
          zoom:15,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
        setInterval('mark()',5000);
    }

    function mark()
    {
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),mapProp);
        var file = "gps.txt";      //read file
        $.get(file, function(txt) { 
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                console.log(lines[i]);
                var words=lines[i].split(",");
                if ((words[0]!="")&&(words[1]!=""))
                {
                marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]),});
                marker.setMap(map);
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]));
                document.getElementById('sat').innerHTML=words[3];
                document.getElementById('speed').innerHTML=words[4];
                document.getElementById('course').innerHTML=words[5];
                }
            }
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    ///***this one is the load method of j-query. why should i need this.***    
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("gps.txt");
    });
  });

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>

<?php




    echo '

    <!-- Draw information table and Google Maps div -->


    <div id="div1">
        <center><br />
            <b> SIM908 GPS position DEMO </b><br /><br />
            <div id="superior" style="width:800px;border:1px solid">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Satellites</td>
                        <td>Speed OTG</td>
                        <td>Course</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="time">'. date("Y M d - H:m") .'</td>
                        <td id="sat"> </td>
                        <td id="speed"></td>
                        <td id="course"></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:800px;height:700px;"></div>
        </center>
    </div>';



    ?>
    </body>
     <body>
     <button>Get External Content</button>
      /// button to access another file

   </body>
   </html>

   <?php } ?>
```

i was trying to run this file on localhost, but it seems that the marker is not shown on the map. and the data in the file called gps.txt is not inserted on the table i created. i don't know why. however, there is some advice that my teacher tell me is "Load J-query", and Initialize map and markers. am not quite sure if this version has been initialized already.

Comment: Why are you using an interval for call `mark` function?

Comment: to make it update all the time

Comment: i just ran some debug and found the error.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: there are two errors...any help appreciated

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


below this line, it says "GET 'http:/localhost/local/map~jquery1.10.1.js 403 forbidden'

Comment: and 
  function mark()
  {
   map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),mapProp);
      var file = "gps.txt";
      $.get(file, function(txt) {{{{{ 
    //"below this line, it says 'unCaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' however i don't know how to define"}}}}.
          var lines = txt.split("\n");
    for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
     console.log(lines[i]);
     var words=lines[i].split(",");
     if ((words[0]!="")&&(words[1]!=""))

Comment: The last error is linked to the first error. Where is the jQuery file in your site? Is it in the root?

Comment: you mean to load jquery ?????

Comment: Yes...sabotero...it's there in the same folder with this file in the root